# MySQL Converting to DateTime

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a mysql db, which has a column date, but it's varchar and formatted like this '01/05/2012' but i need to convert it to datetime format because i will do some datetime comparisons.

What can i do?

Thanks

Comment: Try this [link](https://www.google.lv/search?aq=f&ix=ucb&ie=UTF-8&q=mysql+date+functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d/%m/%Y') FROM tbl;
```

Comment: Why `'%e/%c/%Y'` and not `'%d/%m/%Y'`? Is one more universal than the other (particularly, when converting from a string)? I mean, I don't mind either of them, just curious, because `'%d/%m/%Y'` matches the OP's example better, and yet you are using `'%e/%c/%Y'` here.

Comment: @AndriyM: Actually, you're right: from the OP's question the format should be `%d/%m/%Y`; I have updated my answer.  I had originally written `%e/%c/%Y` out of habit since I usually prefer single-digit days & months when using d/m/YYYY format.

Comment: [I've just checked](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/371), and turns out both formats work correctly with either `'01/05/2012'`- or `'1/5/2012'`-like dates. (Like I said, I was curious. :) Not too much, but SQL Fiddle is such a great thing for these little checks, I just couldn't help it.)